# Show desktop version of site in mobile

Tags: html, meta-tags

What viewport do I need to add to the viewport meta tag in order view a desktop version of a mobile site while browsing?

Comment: This could give you an idea: http://css-tricks.com/user-opt-out-responsive-design/

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question but the answer might still come in handy. 
To view a desktop version of a website on a mobile, just remove the tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

from the `<head> </head>` section of your html code.

Answer (score 0):

For a responsive design use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This has been taken from [Web Tuts Plus](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972), who have a full round-up of the best practices, when using this meta tag.

Obviously, this will only work if you have a responsive design (i.e. a fluid percentage based grid, and media queries).